# Is a component properly layouted or properly layout?

Tags: word-form

If I want to use *layout* as an adjective, do I need to change its end part? If a component has been formatted and positioned using a layout that is properly configured, which should I use?

1. The component is properly **layout**.

or

2. The component is properly **layouted**.

Comment: In English _layout_ cannot be verbed. In fact a more natural version would be _The component is properly *rendered*_.

Comment: @ccpizza Interesting point. Why wouldn't I be able to veribify this (or any other) word? I've always thought that **any** noun could be used as a verb. E.g. *a horse* and *horsing (around)* or *a beer*, *(hey, buddy) beer (me)*.

Comment: Indeed, while the general rule in English is that _Any noun can be verbed, and any verb can be nouned_ (which to me sounds both funny and ugly), there are always exceptions, and the easiest way to verify it would be a good dictionary, such as Webster's Unabridged, OED, or American Heritage - all of them list *layout* only as noun. For non-native speakers I would highly recommend LDOCE. And for style issues The Elements of Style is the de-facto standard: free original edition: http://www.bartleby.com/141/, the modern edited and expanded edition: http://goo.gl/xWI2zZ)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adjective? I'm afraid, it's not.

However, if you want to use 'layout' in that way, you may say..

> The component is properly ***laid out***.

Check [WW Online](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=layout) ...

> layout - A plan or design of something that is ***laid out***

---

Tip: Modify the 'main verb' in words like 'lay out', 'kick off', switch on/off and not the other word. Said that, it'll be laid, kicked, switched respectively. So, never modify 'out' as 'outed', 'off' as 'offed' and so on!

Comment: I thought I was using the verb *layout*. As opposed to *lay out*. Perhaps it's not a real word (yet) despite my autocomplete's opinion, hehe.

Comment: Still...a single word 'layout' is a [noun](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/layout?q=layout)

Comment: Of course *a layout* is a noun but when used as a transitive verb, i.e. *to layout sth*, I'd say it's a verb. Am I mistaken? Of course, I just realized that the correct form will be **layouted** then.